# ObservableCollection property of an object exposed through view model expression-bodied member does not update view

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

My view model has an `AppToolbarService` object that maintains an `ObservableCollection<AppToolbarButton>` property and several methods to operate on the collection:

```
    public ObservableCollection<AppToolbarButton> Buttons { get; }

    public void AddButton(AppToolbarButton button, int index = -1)
    {
        if (Buttons.Any(buttonVm => buttonVm.Id == button.Id))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (index > -1)
        {
            Buttons.Insert(index, button);
        }
        else
        {
            Buttons.Add(button);
        }
    }
```

My view model has its own `ObservableCollection<AppToolbarButton>` that exposes the service's collection as an expression-bodied property:

```
protected IAppbarService AppbarService { get; }

public ObservableCollection<AppbarToolbarButton> Buttons => AppbarService.Buttons;

public MapViewModel(IAppbarService appbarservice){
    AppbarService = appbarService;

    NavigateToEngineer = new Command<MapView>(OnNavigateToEngineerAsync);

    AppbarService.AddButton(new AppToolbarButton(){
        Command = NavigateToEngineer
    });
}

public Command<MapView> NavigateToEngineer { get; }

private Task OnNavigateToEngineerAsync(MapView mapView) {
    AppbarService.RemoveAll();
    AppbarService.AddButton(new AppbarToolbarButton(/* the new button I want to display */));
    ...
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0" x:Name="MainAppContent">
        <views:ItemsStack ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <views:ItemsStack.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Text="{Binding Title}" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference MainMapView}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </views:ItemsStack.ItemTemplate>
        </views:ItemsStack>
        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <esriUI:MapView x:Name="MainMapView"  Map="{Binding Map}" >

                <esriUI:MapView.InteractionOptions>
                    <ui:MapViewInteractionOptions IsRotateEnabled="False" />
                </esriUI:MapView.InteractionOptions>

                <esriUI:MapView.Behaviors>
                    <local:MapTappedBehavior Command="{Binding MapTapped}" />
                </esriUI:MapView.Behaviors>
            </esriUI:MapView>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

After `OnNavigateToEngineerAsync` my stack of buttons does not update.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the UI to update, a `PropertyChanged` event must be triggered. Your `AppToolbarService.Buttons` is probably issuing `PropertyChanged` events when you do an `Add()` but your UI is not bound to `AppToolbarService`, it is bound to your ViewModel.

I do not think that the `AppToolbarService.Buttons`'s `PropertyChanged` events bubble up to your ViewModel's `Buttons` collection.

In order to make this work, you either need to modify the ViewModel's `Buttons` collection directly, or you need to trigger `PropertyChanged` events on your ViewModel's `Buttons` collection which would probably require some weird/poor code since your service should not directly connect to your ViewModel like that.